# How do you save a 2D array in a file and be able to modify the array without losing the previous data? JAVA

Tags: java

```
int[] [] myArray = new int [20] [30]; //Creates 2D Array
```

How can I create this array, enter a value, save it, and be able to modify it once the program is ran again without losing the previous data.

For example: if user enters row as 1 and column as 2 it will store the number 1(meaning it is occupied) in that element and is saved in a file. But if the program is ran again the previous data is lost and the values are all set to back zero. How can i do this without losing the previous data?

I'm a beginner programmer and it is my first time asking a question on this site. I have been stuck on this for the past two weeks, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: this looks like a homework question.

Comment: Well, arrays are serializable, so you can just do that.  To "save it again" you'd need to use a different file name to avoid over writing the previous copy.

Comment: How can I use a different filename each time the program is executed?

Comment: Probe the file system with `File.exists()` if it already exists, permute the file  name and probe again.